# Retrieve Windows 10 product key from hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, motherboard, product-key

Is it possible to retrieve a Windows 10 product key from a hard drive with a valid windows installation on it?

I already tried connecting it via USB to another computer and using "ProduKey" software, but it didn't work.

The computer it came from fried (HDD still works) and it doesn't have the product key sticker on it.

Comment: @miroxlav Positive; There is absolutely no reason to retrieve a Windows 10 product key.  Windows 10 will automatically activate on any machine it’s previously been activated on.

Comment: Even if you were to retrieve they key, it couldn’t be used, OEM license keys cannot be transferred.  If you are still [determined](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases) to find that yourself so be it.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm installing it on a new computer as the original one is toast. Also, I followed the directions in the thread that was posted and I got an error in ProduKey: "Error 1314: A required privelage is not held by the client".

Comment: Sounds like you have not taken ownership of the registry hive.  But you won’t be able to activate the license even if you retrieve it

Comment: Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Do what?  Take ownership of a file.  I wouldn’t do that without creating an image of the HDD first.  I also have my doubts it will work even then due to whom owns the key, within the hive, it’s not a user account but the system account of another installation.  You would have to boot to the HDD, using a VM, might work but you will still have licensing issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75223/discussion-between-ramhound-and-harvey).

Comment: You could just put the old HDD in the new computer and use it as the main drive. You'll have to reactivate though and I don't know if it will let you. Then again, I don't know if it will let you use the OEM key on a different motherboard anyway. You could also try just installing Windows 10 on the new computer, some mobos have SLIC licenses baked in and will automatically activate as Microsoft is really pushing Windows 10 so that they can sell all of your usage data / location / etc.

Comment: @Ramhound `There is absolutely no reason to retrieve a Windows 10 product key`. Except in any case where you are trying to install it on a new device and all you have is an HDD from the old one, or just a full backup. Which can be prompted by damaged/failed components or a device lost in a fire.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - No; OEM licenses cannot be transferred;

Comment: You're assuming it's an OEM license. I made no mention of the type of license.